# Internal additions in additive categories agree with given ones

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories

I know that if $\mathcal C$ is a semiadditive category, then for every two objects $A$, $B$, the set $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C} (A, B)$ is automatically endowed with a structure of commutative monoid, in which the operation $+$ is defined by
$$ f+g = \nabla (f \oplus g) \Delta $$
for any $f,\,g: A \to B$, where $\Delta$ and $\nabla$ are the diagonal and codiagonal morphisms. Moreover, composition turns out to be bilinear.

I remember reading that, when $\mathcal{C}$ is additive, this operation agrees with the one given by definition on each hom-set. I would like to know where I can find a detailed proof of this assertion, since I haven't been able to prove it myself (and I'm not even sure if "agrees" here means that the two groups are just isomorphic, or something stronger). Thanks.

Comment: Use the Eckmann–Hilton argument.